# SQL count distinct # of calls 6 months prior to create date

Tags: sql, date, count, teradata, where-clause

Am trying to figure out the SQL to:

1. count # of distinct calls
2. made on an account 6 months prior to the account being created

I also need to CAST the date field.
I'm thinking something like:

```
case when (call_date as date format 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
between (create_date as date format 'MM/DD/YYYY') and 
(ADD_MONTHS, (create_date as date format 'MM/DD/YYYY), -6) 
then COUNT (DISTINCT call_nbr) as calls
```

Here's a snippet of the data i am working with.  The answer I require 3 Calls.

Note: both dates are flagged in the db table as DATE format.

- Call_Nbr.....Call Date......Create Date
- 12345........03/14/2020....07/23/2020.....*include in result set*
- **12345**........03/14/2020....07/23/2020.....*exclude in result set*
- 45678........02/14/2020....07/23/2020.....*include in result set*
- 91011........01/20/2020....07/23/2020.....*include in result set*
- 91211........**01/24/2020**....07/23/2020.....*exclude in result set*
- 12345........**11/14/2019**....07/23/2020.....*exclude in result set*

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: What are the datatypes of columns `call_date` and `create_date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select count(distinct call_nbr) no_calls
from mytable
where call_date >= add_months(create_date, -6)
```

If you have a column that represnets the `account_id`, then you can use a `group by` clause to get the count of calls *per account*:

```
select account_id, count(distinct call_nbr) no_calls
from mytable
where call_date >= add_months(create_date, -6)
group by account_id
```

---

*Edit*: it seems like you want conditional aggregation instead:

```
select 
    account_id, 
    count(distinct case when call_date >= add_months(create_date, -6) then call_nbr end) no_calls
from mytable
group by account_id
```

Comment: I think this will restrict the data set results to ONLY those records where call_date >= add_months(create_date, -6).

I want to bring in ALL ACCOUNTS created (within a specified date range), however, limit the CALL COUNT to those within the 6 month range.

Hopefully this make sense.